# How to add 'view cart' section to a page using woocomerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to make a section at the top of my page for customers to be able to access their cart. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add view cart button anywhere you want, here is the simple html :

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
<p>
<a href="http://site_name/shop/cart/" class="button">View Cart
<a href="http://site_name/shop/checkout/" class="button checkout">Checkout
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool thank you! is there a way to have a drop down view cart? like a quick overview by hovering over the link?

Comment: @LEWC : search about mini-cart. woocommerce has a widget "mini cart". that might help you.